# C# Project on virtual properties only

Tags: c#, linq, properties, virtual, projection

I am trying to make a generic function that takes as a parameter an IEnumerable and returns also an IEnumerable but projected on the virtual properties, 
I know I can do the following

```
public IEnumerable<T> ProjectOnVirtuals(IEnumerable<T> records)
{
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetMethod.IsVirtual);
    List<T> result = new List<T>();
    foreach (var row in dataTableList)
    {
        var values = properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(row, null));
        result.AppendLine(values);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But like this I won't be able to access it like an IEnumerable of anonymous objects which what I want to achieve

My target is like the following

```
public IEnumerable<T> ProjectOnVirtuals(IEnumerable<T> records)
{
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetMethod.IsVirtual);
    // project records on properties that are virtual
    return records.Select(properties); // this doesn't work
}
```

Example of usage of targeted function

Classes:

```
class Student 
{ 
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int age {get; set;}
    public virtual OtherInfoClass1 OtherInfoObject2 {get; set;}
    public virtual OtherInfoClass2 OtherInfoObject1 {get; set;}
}

class OtherInfoClass1
{
    public string Address {get; set;}
        .
        .
        .
}

class OtherInfoClass2
{
    public string strObject {get; set;}
        .
        .
        .
}
```

Usage of function:

```
IEnumerable<Student> students; // this list of student objects contains the OtherInfoClass object "OtherInfoObject"

var projectedStudents = ProjectOnVirtuals(students);
// projectedStudents this list should be equivalent to the following code in a generic way
var projectedStudents = students.Select(std => new {std.OtherInfoObject1, std.OtherInfoObject2});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Projecting to the same type does not make much sense for me.

Comment: This is a statement, not a question. If your code is not doing what you want it to do, you should describe the differences between what you want and what you get. Giving some background as for how this code fits into the overall structure of your project would be useful as well.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I described what function I am trying to make.
The code I wrote is a pseudo-code of the function I am trying to achive

Comment: @MohammadHamoud What result are you trying to get exactly?

Comment: What are the return types of the properties and do they have a common base or interface? If not, then you cannot create a polymorphic `IEnumerable<>`. Please include some sample code of `T` would look like, otherwise the question might be closed.

Comment: @ja72 added more explaination

Comment: @stybl added more explaination

Comment: Of what use to you is `projectedStudents`? You wouldn't know the names of the members, anonymous objects are strongly typed so you couldn't do anything without more reflection. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks I solved my original problem
Although I still would like to know if there is a way to perform this method